# MyEclipse Web project : deployment assembly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-assembly-plugin, myeclipse

Using MyEclipse 2015 with the Maven plugin, I was once able to conditionally select which Maven dependencies to deploy to my Tomcat server from the "deployment assembly" configuration screen :

[image]

I created a new project, which probably missed one configuration, as I can't choose anymore which dependency to deply, and I have to deploy everything :

[image]

(I don't have the blue circles anymore .....)

The reason why I'm trying to do this is because MyEclipse seems to ignore the  dependency type when deploying a Web application locally.

Does anyone have an idea what could be different between my 2 projects settings ?

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency definition in your POM should specify a scope of "provided" if you don't want it deployed. MyEclipse uses that information, so you shouldn't have to worry about matching maven settings to eclipse project settings.

Comment: Correct ... but unfortunately, because of this : https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/incorrect-deployment-with-scope-provided/ ... we need to find a workaround. It seems that the <provided> scope is not correctly interpreted by MyEclipse. It works well when I package my application with Maven, but not when I deploy it on the MyEclipse embedded server.

Comment: I couldn't replicate that problem in ME 2015, which is what you appear to be using. Note that the problem in the forum was specific to certain versions of certain servers and appeared to be fixed by release 11 (renamed "2013"). Sometimes, dependencies pull in other dependencies, not listed directly in the pom. This might be exacerbating the issue.